# Where does a Perl subroutine get values missing from the actual parameters?

Tags: perl, optional-parameters, subroutine

I came across the following Perl subroutine `get_billable_pages` while chasing a bug. It takes 12 arguments.

```
sub get_billable_pages {
    my ($dbc,
        $bill_pages,      $page_count,      $cover_page_count,
        $domain_det_page, $bill_cover_page, $virtual_page_billing,
        $job,             $bsj,             $xqn,
        $direction,       $attempt,
    ) = @_;

    my $billable_pages = 0;

    if ($virtual_page_billing) {
        my @row;
        ### Below is testing on the existence of the 11th and 12th parameters ###
        if ( length($direction) && length($attempt) ) {
            $dbc->xdb_execute("
                SELECT convert(int, value)
                FROM   job_attribute_detail_atmp_tbl
                WHERE  job             = $job
                AND    billing_sub_job = $bsj
                AND    xqn             = $xqn
                AND    direction       = '$direction'
                AND    attempt         = $attempt
                AND    attribute       = 1
            ");
        }
        else {
            $dbc->xdb_execute("
                SELECT convert(int, value)
                FROM job_attribute_detail_tbl
                WHERE job             = $job
                AND   billing_sub_job = $bsj
                AND   xqn             = $xqn
                AND   attribute       = 1
            ");
        }
        $cnt = 0;
        ...;
```

But is sometimes called with only 10 arguments

```
$tmp_det = get_billable_pages(
    $dbc2,
    $row[6],          $row[8],          $row[7],
    $domain_det_page, $bill_cover_page, $virtual_page_billing,
    $job1,            $bsj1,            $row[3],
);
```

The function does a check on the 11th and 12th arguments.

- What are the 11th and 12th arguments when the function is passed only 10 arguments?
- Is it a bug to call the function with only 10 arguments because the 11th and 12th arguments end up being random values?
- I am thinking this may be the source of the bug because the 12th argument had a funky value when the program failed.
- I did not see another definition of the function which takes only 10 arguments.

Comment: yikes! this is why once you have more than 2 or 3 parameters it's nearly always better to take a single hashref (or hash if you prefer), with named keys. Long parameter lists are a common source of bugs.

Comment: ...and looks like the author is doing a similar thing with a database query - putting a list of selected values into an array (@row), rather than a either a named hashref, or a list of named scalars. Again, a common source of bugs

Comment: @plusplus Not to mention that they're not using placeholders with their queries to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values are copied out of the parameter array `@_` to the list of scalar variables.

If the array is shorter than the list, then the excess variables are set to `undef`. If the array is longer than the list, then excess array elements are ignored.

Note that the original array `@_` is unmodified by the assignment. No values are created or lost, so it remains the definitive source of the actual parameters passed when the subroutine is called.

***ikegami*** suggested that I should provide some Perl code to demonstrate the assignment of arrays to lists of scalars. Here is that Perl code, based mostly on his edit

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $x = 44;             # Make sure that we
my $y = 55;             # know if they change

my @params = (8);       # Make a dummy parameter array with only one value

($x, $y) = @params;     # Copy as if this is were a subroutine

print Dumper $x, $y;    # Let's see our parameters
print Dumper \@params;  # And how the parameter array looks
```

**output**

```
$VAR1 = 8;
$VAR2 = undef;

$VAR1 = [ 8 ];
```

So *both* `$x` and `$y` are modified, but if there are insufficient values in the array then `undef` is used instead. It is as if the source array was extended indefinitely with `undef` elements.

Now let's look at the logic of the Perl code. `undef` evaluates as *false* for the purposes of conditional tests, but you apply the [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) operator like this

```
if ( length($direction) && length($attempt) ) { ... }
```

If you have `use warnings` in place as you should, Perl would normally produce a `Use of uninitialized value` warning. However `length` is unusual in that, if you ask for the length of an `undef` value (and you are running version 12 or later of Perl 5) it will just return `undef` instead of warning you.

Regarding *"I did not see another definition of the function which takes only 10 arguments"*, Perl doesn't have function templates like C++ and Java - it is up to the code in the subroutine to look at what it has been passed and behave accordingly.

Comment: I was about to say "Borodin will soon tell you to use warnings and use strict". He almost certainly doesn't have them on because of the un-my'd `$cnt=0;`

Comment: Wasn't there a change in 16.3 to how length works on variables that are undef?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen It was [12.0](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5120delta.pod#Other-potentially-incompatible-changes): "`length undef` now returns `undef`."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks, couldn't remember the version.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: *No one* can remember the version. That's why we all keep a crib sheet of significant semantic changes together with the date and version of theor inception.

Comment: @ialarmedalien: Thanks for picking up on my `Paerl` typo, but your *"slight grammar"* fixes were just wrong, and certainly too trivial to warrant a third-party edit.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a bug. The remaining arguments are "undef" and you can check for this situation

```
sub foo {
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    print " x is undef\n" unless defined $x;
    print " y is undef\n" unless defined $y;

}

foo(1);
```

prints

```
 y is undef
```

Comment: This is just the standard behaviour of list assignment; it's not anything special about function parameters.